# How to deploy elasticsearch-head or some other browser frontend monitoring tool on my remote server

Tags: java, solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I have an elastic-search node running on a remote GNU/Linux box with limited privileges in my organization. I connect to the server through putty. I would like to have web-browser visibility for the running node for easy of monitoring and visibility. I tried to get elasticsearch-head but I am unable to deploy as per the instructions on github because I don't have `npm install` or `grunt server` or anything like that and nor can I install those programs due to my restricted environment. I do have a few ports open to the machine. Ideally, I need a web-frontend program for elasticsearch that I can simply download and untar on the machine and run some executable to start a built-in server exposing the frontend on some port. Is there an elasticsearch frontend that exists for my situation? Or is there a way I can use head in my situation? Please provide details.

Thank you.

Comment: There is a list of helper projects [on the es website](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/clients/), scroll down to front ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are organizational and security restrictions in the company the questioner works for, things like git clone or the Open command don't work on the company's remotely managed data-center localized server. If the server has python installed, all you have to do it this:
Copy elasticsearch-head downloaded directory to the plugins directory of the elasticsearch engine location. Then navigate to the elasticsearch-head directory and run the following:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 1234
```

The 1234 is the port you want to have the server listen on for http depend's on the firewall rules set on the remote server you are connecting to.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Elastic Head](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/) in the past. Worked quite well!

Edit 1:

You don't *have* to use the npm installer. ES-Head works out of the file system as well. From the docs:

```
git clone git://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head.git
cd elasticsearch-head
open index.html
```

Instead of `git clone`, you could simply download the archive:

```
https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head/archive/master.zip
unzip elastic-head-master.zip
cd elastic-head-master
open index.html
```

Comment: @ramseykhalaf - my bad, have added details where ES-Head can be used without npm, just as OP requires.

Comment: the restricted linux server does not accept the open command in other words.

Comment: You can run es-head from any client machine using the steps mentioned. No server install required.